# calculating a git packfile sha1 checksum in java

Tags: git, checksum, jgit

I am learning about the Git packfile and currently trying to reproduce (in Java) what I believe to be the SHA1 20-byte checksum for the entire packfile. 
I take the byte array from, and including, the "PACK" 4-byte header to the end of the last packaged object's compressed data. Everything I have read indicates that the next 20 bytes is the SHA1 checksum for the entire packfile.

The 20-byte checksum that is part of the byte array received from Git is:
B910248BF9B63AC53595E3835CA57BDAF08DA830

I use the following to calculate my own SHA1 checksum:


`crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

crypt.reset();

crypt.update(testData);

byte [] result = crypt.digest();`

My result ends up as:
B910248BF9B63AC53595E3835CA57BDAF08DA813

I am baffled at how only the last byte of my result can be different from Git's (if I am using the correct part of the byte stream).
If the only problem was the range of data passed to digest() then the entire calculated checksum would most likely look different.

Any ideas?

Comment: As you say, extremely unlikely that you would get a SHA-1 that is almost the same (it should be the same or completely different). Is this consistent with many input files? Also, take a look at the source for jgit, how they calculate it.

Comment: I use the same code to generate test SHA1 ids for each contained object and they match the references in the tree objects. This problem currently only involves calculating the checksum over the entire packfile. I am going to test it with a separate, simpler project and see if I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

use JGit:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] { ... };
ObjectInserter.Formatter f = new ObjectInserter.Formatter();
ObjectId id = f.idFor(OBJ_BLOB, data);
String hash = id.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

The git object-id is calculated as such (pseudocode) :

```
sha1(obj_type | 0x20 | ascii(data_length) | 0x00 | data);
```

where `obj_type` can be `blob`, `commit`, `tree` or `tag`.

Some Java code :

```
byte[] getObjectId(String type, byte[] input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");  
    md.update(String.format("%s %d\u0000", type, input.length).getBytes()); 
    md.update(input);
    return md.digest(); 
}
```

`getObjectId("blob", "helloworld".getBytes())` returns
`620ffd0fd9579a46e46ef4505b198ee0a01a57f2`.
This is same value as what is returned by `git hash-object` command.